# Inserir um Intervalo de Datas

Tags: php, html, mysql, data

Bom dia, estou fazendo um sistema que preciso registrar as presenças de usuários em um evento, separando por período do dia e data. A parte do período foi simples, porem a da data me vem um problema, eu preciso pegar a data do formulário que insere a Data Inicial/Data Final e inserir todas as datas nesse intervalo(alem das datas já inseridas), para registrar a presença do usuário em cada um dos dias por exemplo.
Ficaria tipo assim:

```
   idevento  |        datainicial     |          datafinal
       1     | $_POST["datainicial"]  | $_POST["datafinal"]
       1     |         20/02/2016     |        25/02/2016
```

Ai no banco ficaria assim:

```
       |idevento|   datas  |   
       |   1    |20/02/2016|
       |   1    |21/02/2016| 
       |   1    |22/02/2016|
       |   1    |23/02/2016|
       |   1    |24/02/2016|
       |   1    |25/02/2016|
```

Achei em algumas perguntas algo semelhante mas era somente o select, o que me adiantaria na hora de pegar as datas do banco para registrar a presença, porem eu precisava ter as datas inseridas no banco pra poder registrar a presença em cada uma separada e gerar um Relatório final de presença, então tentei adaptar, porem não obtive resultado.

*EDIT 1:* @Gabriel Herning Fiz o codigo desta forma, porem não sei se estou mandando errado ao banco ou coisa parecida. Devo criar uma nova coluna pra armazenar o valor das datas certo? Alem da de data inicial e data final

```
$dataInicial = $_POST['data'];
$dataFinal = $_POST['datafinal'];
$start = new DateTime($dataInicial);
$end = new DateTime($dataFinal);

$periodArr = new DatePeriod($start , new DateInterval('P1D') , $end);

foreach($periodArr as $period) {
    $end = $period->format('d/m/Y');
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO evento (id, datas) VALUES('$id', '$end); 
}
```

A tabela tem os campos idevento, datainicial, datafinal, e datas, preciso passar qual delas no insert?

*EDIT2:* Esse e o codigo atual

```
function presenca($datas){ 
        include "conectar.php";    
        $dataInicial = $_POST['data'];
        $dataFinal = $_POST['datafinal'];
        $start = new DateTime($dataInicial);
        $end = new DateTime($dataFinal);
        $periodArr = new DatePeriod($start , new DateInterval('P1D') , $end);
        foreach($periodArr as $period) {
            $period->format('d/m/Y');
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO datas (datas) VALUES('$period')"); 
        }
        $conn = null;
```

}

```
if($_POST["pagina"] == "inserirEve"){   
    presenca($_POST['data'], $_POST['datafinal']);
}

<form method="POST" action="input.php">
<input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="inserirEve"/>
Data Inicial: <input type="date" name="data">
Data Final: <input type="date" name="datafinal">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Inserir" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
```

E ocorre esse erro aqui:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\semana\input.php on line 53

*EDIT3:*

```
function presenca($datas){ 
            include "conectar.php";    
            $start = new DateTime($_POST['data']);
            $end = new DateTime($_POST['datafinal']);
            $periodArr = new DatePeriod($start , new DateInterval('P1D') , $end);
            foreach($periodArr as $period) {
                $period = $period->format('d/m/Y');
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO datas (datas) VALUES('$period')"); 
            }
            $conn = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca [Date\Time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) para isso. A Date\Time é uma biblioteca nativa do PHP que lhe oferece tudo que é necessário para se trabalhar com datas. Nela, você encontrará a classe [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

Com DatePeriod, você poderá calcular todas as datas dentro de um perído:

```
$start = new \DateTime('2016-02-20');
$end = new \DateTime('2016-02-25');
$periodArr = new \DatePeriod($start , new \DateInterval('P1D') , $end);

foreach($periodArr as $period) {
    echo $period->format('d/m/Y H:i:s').'<br />';
}

//data de término
echo $end->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Saída:

```
20/02/2016 00:00:00
21/02/2016 00:00:00
22/02/2016 00:00:00
23/02/2016 00:00:00
24/02/2016 00:00:00
25/02/2016 00:00:00
```

Um detalhe é sobre a data de término, ela deve ser considerar como "data de corte", ou seja, não é considerada "dentro de um período". Por isso, ela é impressa separadamente

Caso você precisa só utilizar o período interno, visto que já possui início e fim, pode remover a data inicial através da opção DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE:

```
$start = new \DateTime('2016-02-20');
$end = new \DateTime('2016-02-25');
$periodArr = new \DatePeriod($start , new \DateInterval('P1D') , $end , DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach($periodArr as $period) {
    echo $period->format('d/m/Y H:i:s').'<br />';
}
```

Saída:

```
21/02/2016 00:00:00
22/02/2016 00:00:00
23/02/2016 00:00:00
24/02/2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Então, eu preciso passar o Post da data inicial para start, a da final para end e dentro do foreach mandar um insert para o banco, com o valor de periodoArr? Ou mando no insert o valor de ambos?

Comment: @Coelho sim, você passará o $_POST para o $start e o $end. Dependendo do formato que vier, utiliza [DateTime::createFromFormat()] (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) para definir o formato. Após, faça o foreach do resultado e insira linha a linha.

Comment: @GabrielHerning Eu fiz de um jeito, está dando alguns erros, editei a pergunta com o codigo atual.

Comment: @Coelho seu código está com vários problemas. Primeiro, o retorno de DatePeriod é um array de DateTime, como tal, devem ser tratados como objetos. Ou seja, ser usado o método [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Outro erro, é a falta de apóstrofo ao fechar o código `'VALUES('$id', '$end);'`. E, por último, mas não menos importante, você está utilizando a variável $end, no lugar aonde deveria ser $period. Outro ponto, o que realmente pretende salvar na coluna datas? Acredito que esteja com um sério problema de modelagem.

Comment: Bom, a unica coisa que eu preciso salvar são as datas no intervalo entre a primeira Data(inicial) e a data Final,                                           `$periodoArr = $periodoArr->format('d/m/Y'); $periodArr = new DatePeriod($start , new DateInterval('P1D') , $end);` Algo assim? E na parte do `$end = $period->format('d/m/Y');` deixo somente `$period->format('d/m/Y');` Em relação ao fechar o código foi erro de atenção mesmo.

Comment: O problema da sua implementação é que não está de acordo com a [1ª Forma Normal ](http://www.luis.blog.br/primeira-forma-normal-1fn-normalizacao-de-dados.aspx). Nesse caso, você teria que ter uma segunda tabela (que poderia ser chamada de "evento_datas"), ela salvaria, linha a linha, cada data do período. O problema, é que não faço a menor ideia de como você quer salvar no formato atual. Se você adicionar `$period->format('Y-m-d')` no lugar de onde está o `$end` no insert, talvez já resolva do jeito que você quer.

Comment: Sim sim, era essa a ideia mesmo, nessa nova tabela eu devo mandar o insert com as datas e criar dois campos, um com o `idevento int`` e outra com `datas date`, e inserir nesses dois campos?

Comment: Isso. Você deve inserir na tabela `evento`. Recuperar o id inserido, já que está utilizando mysqli, pode usar [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php](mysqli_insert_id). Após, adicione ao foreach inserindo período por perído.

Comment: Eu ainda não consegui inserir, vou continuar tentando, enquanto isso vou deixar aberto aqui. Deixei o código como esta no momento no principal, mas obrigado pela ajuda até aqui.

Comment: `$periodArr->format('d/m/Y');` não existe. $periodArr é um array, apenas isso.

Comment: Você deve passar $period->format e não $periodArr (conforme dito anterior). Outro detalhe é utilizar prepared statements conforme o exemplo no link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9629364/1628790

Comment: Continuo sem conseguir solução, não aparece erro algum, porem não manda ao banco. devo estar mandando o insert errado ou passando os parametros em em  `if($_POST["pagina"] == "inserirEve"){   
    presenca($_POST['data'], $_POST['datafinal']);`, dei um edit novo no principal.

Comment: De onde está vindo a sua variável $conn? Ela não existe no escopo da função. Adicione a linha ` or die(mysqli_error($conn));` ao final de mysqli_query conforme http://stackoverflow.com/a/17053489/1628790 para exibir qualquer erro no insert.

Comment: Elá vem do conectar.php, que e o arquivo / função que conecta com a db, e mesmo com o or die(mysqli_error($conn));, continua sem mostrar erro nenhum. `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma função para retornar todas as datas entre o inicio e o fim antes de inserir no banco de dados:

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo) {
    // formato esperado: YYYY-MM-DD
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2), substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2), substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400;
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}

//chamando a função da seguinte forma
$dt_inicial = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["datainicial"]));
$dt_final = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["datafinal"]));
$array_datas = createDateRangeArray($dt_inicial , $dt_final);

foreach($array_datas as $data){
    //insere os dados no banco
}
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312491/2072674)

Comment: `foreach($array_datas as $data){                                                    include "conectar.php";                                                                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO datas(idevento, datas) VALUES('$idevento', '$array_datas')"); $conn = null; }   `A parte de inserir no banco, eu preciso inserir o array_datas dentro da minha tabela de datas, ou tanto a final quanto a inicial?